# Convert PHP Variable URL with mod_rewrite to clean URL

Tags: php, .htaccess, variables, mod-rewrite

I need to convert a link that contains php variables into a clean link that can be picked up and indexed by Google. I've looked at ways to do this, and using mod_rewrite apparently is the best way to handle this.

Currently my URLs look like this:

```
 http://mysite.com/jobs/view/?j=senior-model-validator-groep-risk-management
```

I'd like to end up looking like this

```
http://mysite.com/jobs/view/senior-model-validator-groep-risk-management
```

It's probably really easy but sadly I know nothing about .htaccess. I tried a few things but I end up with nothing remotely close :-)

Thanks in advance!

Edit: Here's my full .htaccess file based on the help so far:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>  
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteRule ^jobs/view/(.*)$   jobs/view/?j=$1 [L]  
RewriteBase /  
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]  
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Is `/jobs/view/` a directory on the server with an `index.php`?

Comment: No it is not. it's a virtual directory. The url is based on a WordPress page that uses the variable to display the content. the actual .htaccess page is located in the root folder of the site

Answer (score 1):

You may use an .htaccess file at the root of you web site with these rules:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^jobs/view/(.*)$   jobs/view/?j=$1 [L]
```

Do not forget to filter/validate GET input in the script dealing with the data...

Comment: You may need to be more precise in the rule, such as:
RewriteRule ^jobs/view/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)$   jobs/view/?j=$1 [L]

Comment: I've updated the original post in what I have right now based on your answer.. The comment section borked my formatting :-)

Comment: The rule I gave you must be positioned at the end of the rules in your .htaccess file, that is to say just before </IfModule>.

Comment: @Benoit If it's at the end, then it won't get redirected because of the current last rule, which is also `L`ast. So, I'd say the OP has to insert your rule just before his current last one.